# Как вызвать ошибку загрузки самостоятельно AdMob

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, admob

Нужно проверить функционал рекламных позиций, есть ли какой-то способ вызвать AdFailedToLoadEventArgs, с определенными значениями вручную из кода?

Comment: Выключить интернет?

Comment: Здесь https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#public-static-final-int-error_code_app_id_missing описаны коды ошибок, которые можно получить в методе для OnAdFailedToLoad. Можно попробовать вокруг этого сделать тесты. В бою эти ошибки можно получить так 'args.LoadAdError.GetCode()'. К сожалению, я тоже не нашел способов вызвать именно исключение.

Comment: @aepot очень хорошее решение)
Особенно когда мне нужен код 3, а не ошибка нетворка)